# Amazon EMR job with multiple input parameters

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

In Amazon data pipeline, I am creating activity to copy S3 to EMR using Hive.
To achieve it I have to pass two input parameters into EMR job as a step. 
I have searched all most every data pipeline documentation but did not found the way to specify the multiple input parameters.
I also talk with the AWS support team but they are also not clear about it. The way/trick they suggested also not working.

Below is my step arguments and Hive query. Please let me know if anyone has idea to achieve it.

Steps:

```
s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script,--base-path,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/,--hive-versions,latest,--run-hive-script,--args,-f,s3://gwbpipeline-test/scripts/multiple_user_sample_new.hql, -d, "output1=#{output.directoryPath}", -d,"input1=s3://gwbpipeline-test/temp/sb-test/#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd hh-mm-ss')}/input/tbl_users/", -d,"input2=s3://gwbpipeline-test/temp/sb-test/#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd hh-mm-ss')}/input/tbl_user_children/"
```

Hive Query:

```
drop table if exists tbl_users;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl_users (
user_id string, user_first_name string, user_last_name string, user_email string, user_dob string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '${input1}';

drop table if exists tbl_user_children;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl_user_children (
id string, full_name string, birthday string, type string, user_id string, facebook_id string, date_added string
)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '${input2}';

drop table if exists tbl_users_child_output;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE userS3output (
user_id string, user_fname string, user_lname string, child_full_name string, child_dirthdate string )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '${output1}';

INSERT INTO TABLE tbl_users_child_output SELECT u.user_id, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name, c.full_name, c.birthday FROM tbl_users as u join tbl_user_children as c ON u.user_id = c.user_id;
```

Comment: Can you add json of the pipeline definition that shows how you are trying to use this? It would provide context about the type of activity, parameters etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using the following format on step field of EMRActivity:

Basically I changed -d with -hiveconf. Also changed substitution in hive script from  to. I think this is a change made on newer version of hive.

Below is the changed working code:

```
s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script,--base-path,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/,--hive-versions,latest,--run-hive-script,--args,-f,s3://gwbpipeline-test/scripts/multiple_user_sample_new.hql, -hiveconf, "output1=#{output.directoryPath}", -hiveconf,"input1=s3://gwbpipeline-test/temp/sb-test/#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd hh-mm-ss')}/input/tbl_users/", -hiveconf,"input2=s3://gwbpipeline-test/temp/sb-test/#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd hh-mm-ss')}/input/tbl_user_children/"
```

HIVE Query:

```
table if exists tbl_users;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl_users (
user_id string, user_first_name string, user_last_name string, user_email string, user_dob string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '${hiveconf:input1}';

drop table if exists tbl_user_children;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl_user_children (
id string, full_name string, birthday string, type string, user_id string, facebook_id string, date_added string
)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '${hiveconf:input2}';

drop table if exists tbl_users_child_output;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE userS3output (
user_id string, user_fname string, user_lname string, child_full_name string, child_dirthdate string )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '${hiveconf:output1}';

INSERT INTO TABLE tbl_users_child_output SELECT u.user_id, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name, c.full_name, c.birthday FROM tbl_users as u join tbl_user_children as c ON u.user_id = c.user_id;
```

Hope this helps to someone.